# Insights on how to get celltext with linebreaks from a spreadsheet to a XML

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation, opendocument

So,

I'm trying to get the content from a cell in an ODS spreadsheet.

I'm doing something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./table:table-cell[6]/text:p/text()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

The nasty point is that the content of my table-cell have many line breaks and my code can't get to the full text =/

I also tried many variations from the code above but without a success. Can someone give me an advice?

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why line breaks would be a problem, unless by that you mean not literal line breaks (i.e. `&#10;` characters), but some kind of paragraph element similar to `<p>` in HTML. If it's the latter, than that might explain things, since your XPath expression does not return the text content of the element. It returns all text nodes that are *immediate* children of the element. If you just need the plain text content (i.e. all descendant text nodes, no matter how deep), remove `/text()` at the end of your XPath.

I do not understand what is the point of `disable-output-escaping` in your example at all. Please clarify why you think it's needed there.